# How to deploy my maven project as a jar file which will take its dependencies using a pom file?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, deployment, jar

I have seen many threads regarding deploying a jar file for maven projects. But I am having different requirements.

1. I don't have a main class in my maven project.
2. I have some dependencies in my pom.xml file.
3. I need to deploy a jar file with less size which can take the dependencies through its pom file. (I am currently deployed jar with dependencies using IntelliJ IDEA, now it is 56 MB. I need it to be less capacity, using the above way or an alternative way)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally find the solution for this. 
As @JF Meier explained `mvn clean install` does the job. But before that I had to move to the step definitions which was inside the `test` packages. Actually those step definitions are not belongs to the `test` package since it won't test my project.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a jar with *maven* (like `clean install` or `clean deploy`), the jar:

1. does not need to have the *main class*
2. uses the dependencies in the *pom.xml*
3. does not bundle external dependencies into that unless you specifically tell it to

So your requirements seem to be met automatically.

Comment: @Ivan Aracki
I have used "mvn clean install" and the jar file created is not work as the jar file which I have previously created by "build with dependencies". And inside that jar file I can't see a pom.xml even

Comment: The pom.xml is not in the main directory of your jar, but part of the meta information. And you need to specify what you mean by "work". If you do not bundle the dependencies, you cannot just start the jar with java, but need to specify the classpath.

Comment: I think the original question is like this one.

Suppose you create a java project which requires third-party Java libraries. Now you need to bundle your Java project not as an executable jar but as another library. Without bundling all the third-party jars inside your jar, is there a method to do it so that later when someone imports your jar as a library, it automatically gets those other libraries that were required by your library jar.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below steps :- Hope so its will be help you
pack200 can drastically reduce the JAR size.
heck your dependencies via:

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

or take a look at the dep tree like this:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

do you have unused dependencies?if yes Remove the unused dependency in pom.xml file.